# Trying To Join Two Pivot SQL Query Queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've created two sql queries, the first sums Qty of 12 months and the second sums value over 12 months. Im trying to merge these into one query, but no matter what I try it errors.

The expect output would be 24 columns on one row e.g. Jan, JanQty, Feb, FebQty, Mar, MarQty etc.

Any help would be great!

First Query (Qty):

```
SELECT
SUM(JanQty) as 'JanQty',
SUM(FebQty) as 'FebQty',
SUM(MarQty) as 'MarQty',
SUM(AprQty) as 'AprQty',
SUM(MayQty) as 'MayQty',
SUM(JuneQty) as 'JuneQty',
SUM(JulyQty) as 'JulyQty',
SUM(AugQty) as 'AugQty',
SUM(SeptQty) as 'SeptQty',
SUM(OctQty) as 'OctQty',
SUM(NovQty) as 'NovQty',
SUM(DecQty) as 'DecQty'
from (

SELECT
ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
from
(select SUM(T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
from INV1 T0
inner join OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
where t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
group by t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate) s

Pivot
(SUM(QtyBal) FOR Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p

Union ALL

SELECT
ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
from
(select SUM(-T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
from RIN1 T0
inner join ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
where t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
group by -t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate) s

Pivot
(SUM(QtyBal) FOR Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p

) sq
```

Second Query (Value):

```
SELECT
SUM(Jan) as 'Jan',
SUM(Feb) as 'Feb',
SUM(Mar) as 'Mar',
SUM(Apr) as 'Apr',
SUM(May) as 'May',
SUM(June) as 'June',
SUM(July) as 'July',
SUM(Aug) as 'Aug',
SUM(Sept) as 'Sept',
SUM(oct) as 'Oct',
SUM(nov) as 'Nov',
SUM(Dec) as 'Dec'
from (

SELECT
ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
ISNULL([5],0) as May,
ISNULL([6],0) as June,
ISNULL([7],0) as July,
ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
from
(select SUM(T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
from INV1 T0
inner join OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
where t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
group by t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate) s

Pivot
(SUM(Bal) FOR Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p

Union ALL

SELECT
ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
ISNULL([5],0) as May,
ISNULL([6],0) as June,
ISNULL([7],0) as July,
ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
from
(select SUM(-T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
from RIN1 T0
inner join ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
where t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
group by -t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate) s

Pivot
(SUM(Bal) FOR Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p

) sq
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're glad to have you, and we appreciate the full code sample that you provided with this question, as well as the tags indicating your RDBMS platform. Could you also click the 'edit' button and include some more details on what you want your output to look like? Are you hoping for twenty-four columns and two rows, or for twelve columns and four rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    Jan, 
    JanQty
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
        SUM(JanQty) as 'JanQty',
        SUM(FebQty) as 'FebQty',
        SUM(MarQty) as 'MarQty',
        SUM(AprQty) as 'AprQty',
        SUM(MayQty) as 'MayQty',
        SUM(JuneQty) as 'JuneQty',
        SUM(JulyQty) as 'JulyQty',
        SUM(AugQty) as 'AugQty',
        SUM(SeptQty) as 'SeptQty',
        SUM(OctQty) as 'OctQty',
        SUM(NovQty) as 'NovQty',
        SUM(DecQty) as 'DecQty'
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT
            ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
            ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
            ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
            ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
            ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
            ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
            ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
            ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
            ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
            ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
            ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
            ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
                SUM(T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
                MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
            FROM 
                INV1 T0
                 inner join 
                OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
            WHERE 
                t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
            GROUP BY t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate
          ) s

        PIVOT 
          (
            SUM(QtyBal) FOR 
            Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
          ) p

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            ISNULL([1],0) as JanQty,
            ISNULL([2],0) as FebQty,
            ISNULL([3],0) as MarQty,
            ISNULL([4],0) as AprQty,
            ISNULL([5],0) as MayQty,
            ISNULL([6],0) as JuneQty,
            ISNULL([7],0) as JulyQty,
            ISNULL([8],0) as AugQty,
            ISNULL([9],0) as SeptQty,
            ISNULL([10],0) as OctQty,
            ISNULL([11],0) as NovQty,
            ISNULL([12],0) as DecQty
        from
          (
            select 
                SUM(-T0.Quantity) as QtyBal,
                MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
            from 
                RIN1 T0
                 inner join 
                ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
            where 
                t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
            group by -t0.Quantity, t1.DocDate) s

            Pivot
              (
                SUM(QtyBal) FOR 
                Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
              ) p
      ) sqa
  ) qty
     CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
        SUM(Jan) as 'Jan',
        SUM(Feb) as 'Feb',
        SUM(Mar) as 'Mar',
        SUM(Apr) as 'Apr',
        SUM(May) as 'May',
        SUM(June) as 'June',
        SUM(July) as 'July',
        SUM(Aug) as 'Aug',
        SUM(Sept) as 'Sept',
        SUM(oct) as 'Oct',
        SUM(nov) as 'Nov',
        SUM(Dec) as 'Dec'
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
            ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
            ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
            ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
            ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
            ISNULL([5],0) as May,
            ISNULL([6],0) as June,
            ISNULL([7],0) as July,
            ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
            ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
            ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
            ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
            ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
        FROM
          (
            SELECT 
                SUM(T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
                MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
            FROM 
                INV1 T0
                 inner join 
                OINV T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
            WHERE 
                t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
            GROUP BY t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate
          ) s

        PIVOT 
          (
            SUM(Bal) FOR 
            Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
          ) p

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT
            ISNULL([1],0) as Jan,
            ISNULL([2],0) as Feb,
            ISNULL([3],0) as Mar,
            ISNULL([4],0) as Apr,
            ISNULL([5],0) as May,
            ISNULL([6],0) as June,
            ISNULL([7],0) as July,
            ISNULL([8],0) as Aug,
            ISNULL([9],0) as Sept,
            ISNULL([10],0) as Oct,
            ISNULL([11],0) as Nov,
            ISNULL([12],0) as Dec
        from
          (
            select 
                SUM(-T0.LineTotal) as Bal,
                MONTH(T1.DocDate) as Month
            from 
                RIN1 T0
                 inner join 
                ORIN T1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
            where 
                t1.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231' and 
                year(T1.DocDate) = 2014
            group by -t0.LineTotal, t1.DocDate
          ) s

        Pivot
          (
            SUM(Bal) FOR 
            Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
          ) p
      ) sqb
  ) Bal
```